# Node.js SSH2 sending Login data for each read

Tags: node.js, express, ssh, sftp

i'm using the ssh2 package in node.js to build a web client for our SFTP-Server. I want the user to be able to browse through his directories. To do so, I implemented a function that receives JS Objects from the server and put the data into a html table. The table will have a button in each row, that sends another ajax request to the server. The Server will then use sftp.read to return another JS Object to the client which will update the table with the new List.

The problem is, that i have to end the connection every time a user requests a list. So whenever he wants to cd into another directory i need to pass the password and name again. The server will then authenticate the user again and send the requested list back. This is ofc inefficient and probably insecure, so I wonder if there is a better  way to implement this. Here is my nods.js code:

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var pass = req.body.pass;
    var dir = req.body.dir;

    var connSettings = {
      host: '5.9.55.35',
      port: 22,
      username: name,
      password: pass,
    };
    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function(){
      conn.sftp(function(err, sftp){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Login of User " + name + " successful")
        sftp.readdir(dir, function(err, list){
          if(err) throw err;
          res.send(list);
          conn.end();
        });
      });
    }).connect(connSettings);
});

app.post('/goBack', function(req, res){
    var goBackTo = req.body.dir;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var pass = req.body.pass;
    var connSettings = {
      host: '5.9.55.35',
      port: 22,
      username: name,
      password: pass,
    };
    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function(){
      conn.sftp(function(err, sftp){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Login of User " + name + " successful")
        sftp.readdir(goBackTo, function(err, list){
          if(err) throw err;
          res.send(list);
          conn.end();
        });
      });
    }).connect(connSettings);
});

app.post('/explore', function(req, res){
    var nuDir = req.body.dir;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var pass = req.body.pass;
    var connSettings = {
      host: '5.9.55.35',
      port: 22,
      username: name,
      password: pass,
    };
    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function(){
      conn.sftp(function(err, sftp){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Login of User " + name + " successful")
        sftp.readdir(nuDir, function(err, list){
          if(err) throw err;
          res.send(list);
          conn.end();
        });
      });
    }).connect(connSettings);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I know that I could reuse the Client object, thus getting rid of the line that says 'conn.end()'. But the Server wouldn't know the difference between a request from client1 and client2. So if both users have a directory with the name 'pictures' client1 could request a list of his directory, but the object node is working with would reference client2.

I hope I explained everything correctly. I'm faily new to node as this is my first real project. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using sessions of some kind to store per-client data, such as current working directory?

Comment: No, since i didn't know that existed. That should be the solution. I also read about JSON Web Tokens as an alternative. I will fiddle around with express-session for now. Will post the result later